# How can I stop having problems when I use values from a structure as a parameter in a function in C?

Tags: c, data-structures, struct

I'm writing a code that bring the values from a structure called "data", captures it in the main() function and then use the value inside "my_friend.friend_age" as a parameter in the function sum() to sum 20 to the value inside "my_friend.friend_age" and, afterward, return the value and show it to the user.
`

```
#include <stdio.h>
int sum(struct data age);

struct data{
    char name_friend[50];
    int friend_age;
};

struct data my_friend; 

int main(){
    int d;
    printf("Type your friends name: ");
    scanf("%s", &my_friend.name_friend);
    printf("Type your friends age: ");
    scanf("%d", &my_friend.friend_age);
    d= sum(my_friend.friend_age);
    printf("%d", d);
}

int sum(struct my_friend age)
{
    int agein_20;
    agein_20= agein_20 + age;
    return agein_20;
}
```

`
However, at the time of compile it and run it I'm getting errors such as:
[image]
I'd really appreciate your help because I'm not sure about what I'm doing wrong ;)

Comment: `struct my_friend` is not `struct data`

Comment: Change `int sum(struct my_friend age)` to `int sum(int age)`

Comment: Never use `%s` as a specifier for `scanf`, it does not limit how many bytes are stored and thus is guaranteed to be vulnerable to a buffer overflow. Always make sure you limit the input to a specific size.

Comment: Just to point out. the variable `int agein_20` is undefined behavior since its value is not initialized

Comment: `scanf("%s", &my_friend.name_friend);` is wrong, because `&my_friend.name_friend` is not a `char *`. It should be either `scanf( "%s", &my_friend.name_friend[0] );` or `scanf( "%s", my_friend.name_friend );`. Both are equivalent, due to [array to pointer decay](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1461432/12149471).

Comment: Thank u, I could fix it <3

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here are the changes I made:

1. Changed `struct data` to eliminate `friend` part in each variable.
2. Made `my_friend` a local variable instead of a global variable.
3. Specified field width when reading name using a bit of macro magic to convert a number to a string.
4. In first `scanf()` the variable type was incorrect.  It should just be `my_friend.name`.
5. Eliminated the `d` variable.
6. Moved `sum()` before `main()` to get away with not using a separate prototype.

```
#include <stdio.h>

#define str(s) str2(s)
#define str2(s) #s

#define NAME_LEN 49
struct data {
    char name[NAME_LEN];
    int age;
};

int sum(int age) {
    return age + 20;
}

int main(void) {
    struct data my_friend;
    printf("Type your friends name: ");
    scanf("%" str(NAME_LEN) "s", my_friend.name);
    printf("Type your friends age: ");
    scanf("%d", &my_friend.age);
    printf("%d\n", sum(my_friend.age));
}
```